# Разбиение кода на функции. С++

Tags: c++, функции

Есть код программы, которая позволяет ввести динамический массив, а затем
1. Упорядочивает элементы массива по возрастанию.
2. Находит сумму отрицательных элементов массива.
3. Находит произведение элементов массива, расположенных между максимальным и минимальным элементами.
Не получается грамотно разбить код на многофайловый проект.

```
#include "stdafx.h"  
#include <iostream>  
using namespace std;    
double *p, n;
double pr = 1;
int sum, min = 1000000, max = -1000000, i_, j_;

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
    cout << "Введите количество элементов: ";
    cin >> n;
    p = new double[n];

    cout << "Введите элементы массива: ";
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        cin >> p[i];

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        if (p[i] < 0) sum += p[i];
        if (max < p[i]) { max = p[i]; i_ = i; }
        if (min > p[i]) { min = p[i]; j_ = i; }
    }

    if (i_ > j_) swap(i_, j_);
    for (int i = (i_ + 1); i < j_; i++)
        pr *= p[i];

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        for (int j = i; j > 0 && p[j - 1] > p[j]; j--)
            swap(p[j], p[j - 1]);

    cout << "Отсртированный массив: ";
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)

        cout << p[i] << " ";
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Сумма отрицатльных элементов: " << sum <<endl;
    if (pr != 1)
    {
        cout << "Произведение между максимальным  минимальным элементами: "     << pr << endl;
    }
    else
            cout << "Между максимальным и минимальным значениями нет чисел" << endl;

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: В чем ваши трудности? Декомпозируйте задачу: сначала разбейте код на функции, потом уже разнесете по файлам.

Comment: Трудности с синтаксисом. Уже пытался разбивать на функции, но постоянно вылетают ошибки о необъявленных идентификаторах и подобные им. Это мой первый многофаловый проект, еще толком не разобрался что и как.

Comment: Не заморачивайтесь пока о файлах. Сначала разбейте код на функции, которые работают с глобальными переменными. Учитывая, что у вас локальные перменные нужны лишь для итерации по циклуту, то для этого вам достаточно унести отдельные логические куски кода в отдельные функции, а на их месте поставить их вызовы.

Comment: Вторым шагом вы будете избавляться от глобальных переменных, заменяя их локальными, передаваемыми через параметры.

Comment: Пока [это вот](https://pastebin.com/YXJsmfiT) нужно преобразовать примерно в [это](https://pastebin.com/eEVxt14y)

Comment: Ваши ссылки не открываются "Не удается получить доступ к файлу", но вы направили меня в нужном направлении. Спасибо!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ты уже большую часть ответа написал в вопросе.

Нужно выделить такие функции и соответствующим образом их вызвать:

- Ввести динамический массив
- Упорядочивает элементы массива по возрастанию.
- Находит сумму отрицательных элементов массива.
- Находит позицию минимального элемента
- Находит положение максимального элемента
- Находит произведение элементов массива между заданными позициями
- Выводит массив

Comment: Я понимаю, что нужно выделить функции и вызвать их. Моя проблема заключается в том, что у меня не получается синтаксически правильно составить функции и вызвать их. Получаю огромное количество ошибок об необъявленных идентификаторах и подобных им.

Comment: @ЯнБойко, сначала вынеси в одном файле, причём чтобы код функций был расположен до их вызова.

Answer (score 1):

Ну, я бы делал примерно так, с обязательным уничтожением глобальных переменных как класса:

```
#include <iostream>  
using namespace std;

void inputArray(double*&p, int&size)
{
    cout << "Введите количество элементов: ";
    cin >> size;
    p = new double[size];
    cout << "Введите элементы массива:\n";
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        cout << "p[" << i << "] = ";
        cin >> p[i];
    }
}

void outArray(double*p, int size, const char * msg)
{
    cout << msg << "\n";
    for(int i = 0; i < size; ++i) cout << p[i] << "  ";
    cout << "\n";
}

inline void swap(int& a, int& b)
{
    int tmp = a; a = b; b = tmp;
}

void sortArray(double*p, int size)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        for (int j = i; j > 0 && p[j - 1] > p[j]; j--)
            swap(p[j], p[j - 1]);
}

double negSum(double*p, int size)
{
    double sum = 0.0;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        if (p[i] < 0) sum += p[i];
    return sum;
}

void minmax(double*p, int size, int& min_idx, int& max_idx)
{
    double min = p[min_idx = 0], max = p[max_idx = 0];
    for(int i = 1; i < size; ++i)
    {
        if (p[i] < min)
        {
            min = p[min_idx = i];
        }
        else if (p[i] > max)
        {
            max = p[max_idx = i];
        }
    }
}

double product(double*p, int min_idx, int max_idx)
{
    double prod = 1.0;
    for(int i = min_idx; i <= max_idx; ++i)
        prod *= p[i];
    return prod;
}


int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");

    double * p;
    int size;
    inputArray(p,size);
    outArray(p,size,"Исходный массив");

    cout << "Сумма отрицательных элементов = " << negSum(p,size) << endl;

    int min_idx, max_idx;
    minmax(p,size,min_idx,max_idx);

    if (max_idx == min_idx)
    {
        cout << "Между максимальным и минимальным значениями нет чисел" << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Произведение между максимальным и минимальным элементами: "
             << product(p,min_idx,max_idx) << endl;
    }

    sortArray(p,size);
    outArray(p,size,"Отсортированный массив");

    delete[] p;

}
```